# Relatedlist while hovering

Tags: visualforce

Is there anyway to show relatedlist for a link in pageblocktable.
I have account object and its related object called employee(M-D).
I have cost field in employee object and I rolled up the cost field to account object.
Now i have a pageblocktable where I am showing the rollup field of account.

I want to show related list (its distribution) when I hover that Field.
Any Ideas.!

Comment: I would get all related data in the controller and map it with the account id (Map <Id, List <Employee__c>>), pass it to the page and use some custom tooltip javascript library to display the data I want.

Comment: @e-bacho2.0 That seems valid enough to be included as an answer. I would love to give you an upvote for it, can you please include it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!employeeMap}" var="accId" >
     <apex:repeat value="{!employeeMap[accId]}" var="employee" >
        <apex:outputText value="{!employee.Name}"/><br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all related data in the controller and map it with the account id `Map <Id, List <Employee__c>>`, pass it to the page and use some custom tooltip javascript library to display the desired info.

A good old, cross-browser, lightweight tooltip library that I'm using often (official website is down), I've just uploaded it [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6oaxfuvti368c84/boxover2.1a.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Hi @bachovski, link is broken :(

Comment: Apologies @MnZ, link fixed!